# Alternative to Tick Based Systems

Tags: php, html

i am thinking about creating a sort of text based mmorpg game, i have a fair amount of experience in designing and building websites. I see that a lot of text based games use ticks as a sort of time frame for completeing tasks etc... I was wondering if there was an alternative to this, so that the game could constantly be running live, where players didn't have to wait till the end of the tick to complete a task. For example they could the game might involve the player building a house, the system for a tick based game might say your house will be ready in 3 ticks, i want a system where it might say your house will be ready in 3 minutes. Is there anyway to do this? I just need ideas at this stage, so i can continue doing a bit more planning and researching.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean round-based games when talking about ticks?

for the implementation of the minutes-based thing, i suggest to create an event table containing the timestamp, when an event should take place and some information on what to do. when the user visits your game after some time, you can look up which events should have happened since his last visit and execute them. if the execution of the event produced following events,  execute them or insert them into the event table.

if a user never visits your game, nothing will be calculated and you won't need any background service like cron jobs.

Comment: Interesting answer, but I'm wondering if it will create synchronization issues with other players. Remember this is probably multiplayer and whatever that player does, even if absent, will affect the others.

You could do the update when "interested party" players check up on the events. But if these events affect other players who HAVE been checking in all this time... how do you manage that? Go "back in time" and change every other player's event timeline? I see chaos brewing.

Comment: i didn't think this one through to the bitter end, but the system is not distributed so you have one big entity that knows whats going on.  this entity will know which events depend on each other. you can even calculate this dependencies before creating a new event. if you are unsure, execute all events in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it has certainly given me some ideas, i was looking to day and doing some research and found most games of this type are tick driven, and some range from every minute to every day. However i did find one called 'Torn' or torn city, which is real time, and the only one like it from what i can see, does anyone know how they manage to get it real time?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "a tick is one minute", than it's exactly what you want. The main reason to introduce a tick-based solution is, that you can change the game speed (for example to provide a fast and a slow game world) simply by changing the duration of a tick and without touching anything else, especially the the games elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, i don't have a lot of experience with this sort of thing, so if i was to build a text based game on a website using php and mysql could the ticks be created with cronjobs, that were set to execute a number of tasks each minute, is that how ticks work?